# sequences and dilworth's theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, set-theory, order-theory

Can someone please help me understand the last inequality. Specifically how does it follow that m-1 + 1/n-1 >= m.

[image]

Comment: Please don't use pictures of text or formulas.
See [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), why.
Use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

In fact,
$$m - 1 + \frac{1}{n - 1} \gt m - 1.$$
Therefore, size of antichain $\gt m - 1$; since
size of antichain is an integer, this inequality implies size of antichain $\ge m$.

Comment: So since m-1 +1/n-1 > m-1, that means size of antichain is greater than m-1. if it's greater than m-1 that means we can say it must be greater than or equal to m. Correct?